# How do I stop a do while loop, when I input a single word string, instead of that single string in a sentence sentence? not sure how to word it

Tags: java, string, loops, do-while

So, I am making a program where you can only stop the loop if the user writes the word "cookie". Unfortunately when I add the word "cookie" in a sentence, etc "I love cookies", the program stops. How do I keep the program going and just stop when the user puts "cookie". here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Lab6A {
    public static void main(String[]args){
        Scanner game = new Scanner(System.in);
        String cookie;
        String word = "cookie";
        do {
            System.out.print("Gimme a cookie: ");
            cookie = game.next();
        } while (!word.contains(cookie));
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not `!word.equals(cookie)` rather than `!word.contains(cookie))`

Comment: every other way I try, It would not work. What I am trying to do is that, whenever I put cookies in a sentance, I want it to loop and when I just type "cookie" the loop needs to stop.

Comment: nike, i tried equals it works, but I was also trying out contains to see if that works.

Comment: I replaced `new String("cookie")` with `"cookie"` to make your example less confusing (lets not add to examples problems unrelated to asked question). Hope you don't mind.

Comment: ok, do you have any idea about the question?

Comment: With `next()` you are iterating over each words provided by user, so `cookie = game.next();` will not contain `"I love cookies"` but `"I"` `"love"` `"cookies"`. Since `"cookies".contains("cookie")` is true (as "cookie" exists there as *substring*) `while (!word.contains(cookie));` stops the loop. If you want to handle lines, then use `nextLine()` and if you want to check if entire line is only "cookie" then use `equals` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you check whether `word` *contains* `cookie`, it returns true if the user inputs `i` or `e`, because your word `"cookie"` actually contains this letter. So if you write "I love cookies" your code stops, because cookie contains the letter i.

If you check it like this:

```
cookie.equals(word);
```

this just returns true if `cookie` **and** `word` consist of "cookie" and nothing else.